# Android Application Not Sending Notifications

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm encountering an issue with sending notifications to my Android app despite having implemented all necessary additions.

I developed a WebView application and followed the common practices found on various internet sources for implementing notifications. Firstly, in `MainActivity.java`, within the `onCreate` method, I invoked:

```java
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println("Fetching FCM registration token failed");
                    return;
                }

                // Get new FCM registration token
                String token = task.getResult();

                // Log and toast
            }
        });
```

Furthermore, I made the necessary additions to the `MyFirebaseMessagingService.java` file as depicted in various online resources:

```java
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        System.out.println("From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            System.out.println("Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getFrom(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void sendNotification(String from,String body){
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        String channelId = "notification";
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification)
                        .setContentTitle("TeknoFore")
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I also declared the service in `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows:

```xml
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Additionally, I ensured that the `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission was granted and placed the `google-services.json` file in the app directory. However, despite these steps, neither the test notifications sent via token nor the notifications sent directly to the application are being received.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) might help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```java
notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

to

```java
notificationManager.notify(1 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

in one of the examples I read that `notificationId` should be positive

Notifications for a channel can be disabled immediately after creation, possibly due to the `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` flag
This happened on my Xiaomi phone, and so did one other person.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It still doesn't work, the google-services.json file is in the app directory but not on the ide, and the app analytics are completely 0, even though I've opened the app multiple times and tested it on 2 phones except the emulator.

Comment: Addition - I already gave the app permission for notifications, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The channel has its own permissions separately from the application, check them on the installed application. This is done so that you can disable a separate channel. Can you show your channel settings screen on your phone?

Comment: there is no such setting section in my emulator

Answer (score 1):

Update: Yes this is a bit strange but the problem was suddenly solved (I didn't do anything extra) I think it was a timing issue. In this case I found out that the steps I was taking were correct, so I mark the issue as solved.